# create function to add factor according to date range

Tags: r

I'm running various tests in apartment buildings and need to add a factor (Etapp `<i>`) indicating which test phase the observations belong to.
I have created a matrix with test phases and corresponding start and end dates.

```
phases <-matrix(c(t1,t2,t2,t3), ncol = 2,
dimnames = list(c("Etapp I", "Etapp II"), c("Start","Stopp")), byrow = TRUE)

> phases
    Start Stopp
Etapp I 16812 16827
EtappII 16827 16841
```

Variables t1, t2, ... contain breakpoints for test phases, as POSIXct

The main data frame is in wide format containing a column with date (Tid) as id for observations. Size is in the order of a couple thousand observations in 40-50 variables, of which only the date is of importance here.

My plan is to create a function for this as I have several buildings, each with their own dataframe for the observations. The function will take two arguments building data frame and above mentioned matrix phases and return a dataframe with the factor added.

```
addPhase <- function(df, ph) {
  # Merge new variable using dplyr::merge()
}
```

How do I factor these observations according to time in a multi level factor. I managed to set a factor for a single test phase using a logical vector as below

```
factor(as.Date(VitaHusen$Tid) > t1 & as.Date(VitaHusen$Tid) < t2,
labels = c("","Etapp I"))
```

How to expand this to several time frames?
Can I use dimnames from phases to set factor level for my new factor column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following function

```
addPhase <- function(df, ph, varName) {
  ph_names <- rownames(ph)
  for (i in ph_names) { # Iterate for all phases in matrix ph
    ph_start <- ph[i,1] # Extract start date
    ph_end <- ph[i,2]   # Extract end date
    # Assign name of phase to matching rows
    df[as.Date(df$Tid) > ph_start & as.Date(df$Tid) < ph_end, varName]     <- i
  }
  df[[varName]] <- as.factor(df[[varName]]) # Convert to factor
  return(df)
}
```

For one of my test objects, Vimpeln, the call looks like

```
Vimpeln <- addPhase(Vimpeln, phases, "Fas")
```

which adds a factor variable "Fas" to dataframe "Vimpeln" according to dates given in matrix "phases" as defined in question.